# How to know if a device is in dark mode

Tags: c#, maui, .net-maui, darkmode

Is it possible to know if a device is in dark mode from the code behind of a MAUI app?

I'm doing some dynamic color shading at runtime and need to know.

Comment: This link may help: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/handling-light-dark-mode-dotnet-maui 
I see different schemas for light and dark modes.

Comment: Thanks Arthur, this was exactly what I needed.  Specifically this line of code from the article you linked to:  Application.Current.RequestedTheme;  Testing now, hopefully it will work on both Android and iOS.

Comment: You're welcome i was not sure whether `Application.Current.RequestedTheme` returns MAUI local selected theme or it is OS related theme also, @ArthurCam please write it as an answer